# How to stop any dialog windows from showing when inserting a USB drive in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, usb, autorun, usb-flash-drive

**1)**
I just found a really interesting program that allows me to use a USB drive as a windows login key.  It is called [Rohos Logon Key](http://www.rohos.com/products/rohos-logon-key/).  IF I remobve my USB drive/key from the PC then I can have the PC lock or hibernate or any other option, I have been looking for such a solution for many years but never knew one existed until this and it works much better then I imagined.

I do have a couple minor issues though (im using Windows 7 pro).  When I remove and then re-insert my USB key, windows prompts me with this dialog here...

[alt text http://img2.pict.com/f2/31/68/3484361/0/screenshot2b4.png](http://img2.pict.com/f2/31/68/3484361/0/screenshot2b4.png)

Generally when I get this I just click on "**Continue without scanning**"  however I am looking for a solution to just make it not even show this at all, is it possible to  disable it from showing?

---

**2)**

I also get this dialog as well when I insert USB drives/key...
[alt text http://img2.pict.com/d8/7d/6f/3484403/0/screenshot2b5.png](http://img2.pict.com/d8/7d/6f/3484403/0/screenshot2b5.png)

Would it be possible to not show this as well or have it pick an option by default or anything really?

Comment: Have you ever tried clicking "Scan and fix"?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the instruction at the bottom of your 2nd graphic, you should be able to do at least some of what you want.